# load fragment's existing view without recreating it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, back-stack

When I access a fragment from the backstack it appears to redraw the fragment, even going back to the network or database in my OnCreateView method.

I would rather that it behaves more like an activity in the activity stack, where the instance of the activity is still there as I left it.

I **think** this has something to do with "saving the instance state" but I'm not 100% sure, leading me to ask this question before going to deep down the wrong rabbit hole.

How do I load a fragment's existing view instead of having the onCreateView method run again?

Comment: It's part of fragment lifecycle http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

Comment: @betorcs great that confirms some things, now how can I keep the fragment in the state I left it in? putting things in onCreate instead?